# CSS get first-child of an element to display as block

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I cannot figure out the correct selector to select the first element after a div with a class.

```css
.eleSpacing {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2em;
}

div.eleSpacing:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="eleSpacing">
  <label for="fiscalYear">Fiscal Year</label>
  <select id="fiscalYear"></select>
</div>
```

I want the `label` to display above the `select` element.

setting inline style to `display:block;` works exactly how I want but I cannot figure out the correct combination to select it from CSS.

Comment: `div.eleSpacing>label`

Comment: To select any arbitrary `:first-child` element consider: `.eleSpacing *:first-child`, to be more specific (and for the sake of better practice) consider: `.eleSpacing label:first-child`. If `label` is the only child of its type, drop the *pseudo-class* selector and consider: `.eleSpacing label`. If you need to select only *the first label* of an element with a given class consider: `.eleSpacing > label`.

Comment: div.eleSpacing>label? Or :first-of-type

Comment: @BO41 The general sibling combinator will only select sibling `label` elements of `div.eleSpacing` and not nested ones. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Comment: for the record adding changing to *:first-child worked for me and label:first-child also worked.  Oddly enough if I use .eleSpacing:first-child just to set font-weight:bold it works just fine but not for display:block.

Comment: @CharlesMcIntosh `.eleSpacing:first-child` with `font-weight` works, but not in the way that you think. Using that selector, the CSS is being applied to `.eleSpacing`, not the `label` itself. It affects the label because the label is within `.eleSpacing`, but the CSS is being applied to the parent element in that scenario. `*:first-child` works because `*` is a wildcard selector, so you're saying apply this CSS to the first instance of any element within `.eleSpacing`, but as I explained below, `first-child` is only necessary if you have multiple of the same type element within the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent goes first, followed by the child. For example, if I had a div with a class name of ".parent" with a few paragraphs within it, I would do the following if I wanted to make the first paragraph red:

```
.parent p:first-child {
   color: red;
}
```

So in your case, the following should work:

```
div.eleSpacing label:first-child {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `first-child`, just specify the `label` in the CSS selector:

```
.eleSpacing > label {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I will have to re-read about first-child because apparently I don't quite understand its use.

Comment: `first-child` would only be useful here if you had multiple `label` elements as children of the `eleSpacing` element. Since you only have one `label` element, there's no need for `first-child` since it is the _only_ child of that element type.

Answer (score 1):

`:first-child` applies to the selector that it is attached to.  so in your question you are selecting the first `.eleSpacing`

`label:first-child` will find the first label among its siblings.

```css
.eleSpacing {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2em;
}

div.eleSpacing label:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="eleSpacing">
  <label for="fiscalYear">Fiscal Year</label>
  <select id="fiscalYear"></select>
</div>
```